# Lab repeatedly submitted bill to wrong insurance. How do I resolve the issue?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, estate-settlement

I am handling the estate of my late step-father. In November 2021 he was in the hospital and had lab work done. The lab company sent the claim to the wrong insurance. My mother & insurance company called the lab with correct info. Lab has continued to submit to wrong insurance even though they've been given the correct information numerous times. Last month they finally submitted to the right insurance and it was denied for not being filed in a timely manner. EOB says we don't owe but are being billed by the lab. What steps should I take to resolve this?

Comment: talk to an attorney

Comment: Is the lab in-network or out-of-network?

Comment: I agree with @littleadv that an attorney could help here, but my gut feeling is you don't even need to do that unless the lab sues the estate. From your description it seems you did what you could, and the lab clearly messed up and it's up to them to beg the insurance company to pay despite their mistake. They shouldn't even be asking you. Maybe you need to politely remind them of this fact and perhaps they'll stop bugging you about it. If you have an estate attorney, surely they can provide guidance.

Comment: This sounds like a better question for https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the estate solvent?

Answer (score 1):

**Try calling the insurance company.  Explain the situation to a real person and they may be able to fix it.**

If that doesn't work hire a lawyer.

Comment: Agree, and would add that persuading the insurance company costs only your time; hiring a lawyer is expensive. Can call several times if you strike out with the insurer's call center employees at first, just try another time.